# SQL Server 2019 upgrade from Enterprise Evaluation > Developer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Someone installed Enterprise Evaluation on our development server which is about to expire. I wanted to do edition upgrade through the Installation Center but I got an error:

> Rule "SQL Server 2019 edition upgrade" failed.
>
> The selected Sql Server instance does not meet upgrade matrix
> reuqirements. The source Enterprise edition upgrading from and the
> target Developer edition upgrading to is not allowed.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15

Upgrade from SQL Server 2019 (15.x) Evaluation Enterprise** to SQL Server 2019 (15.x) Developer should be supported. It is not a clustered instance.

```
SELECT @@VERSION;
```

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU11) (KB5003249) - 15.0.4138.2 (X64)
May 27 2021 17:34:14
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Add the output of `SELECT @@VERSION;` to your question.

Comment: It's in the last line.

Comment: The last line isn't the full output of that query.

Comment: You're right. I updated my question.

Comment: Your error message refers to Enterprise --> Developer. That's not listed as a valid path in the linked page. The allowed path you quote is Enterprise *Evaluation* --> Developer.

Comment: Thank you @DougDeden. You found the problem.

Comment: That's good to hear. I'll write it up as an answer. Hmmmm. You mention "about to expire", but then the result of `SELECT @@VERSION` indicates that you do not have an Evaluation Edition. If you could clarify that, it might change the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message doesn't match the title of your question.

Your error message refers to upgrading Enterprise Edition to Developer Edition. And that's not listed as a valid upgrade/conversion path in the linked page.

The allowed path you seem to be looking at is Enterprise Evaluation --> Developer.

Based on the error message, and the output of your `SELECT @@VERSION`, you are running Enterprise Edition, and that's not eligible for an in-place conversion to Developer Edition.

To move from Enterprise Edition to Developer Edition, you'll need to uninstall and do a fresh install -- taking backups first as appropriate. Or even better, do a fresh install on a new server, so you can still refer to your existing instance in case of any problems. There are several articles elsewhere discussing the pros and cons.

- https://sqlserver-help.com/2014/11/25/help-how-to-downgrade-sql-server-edition-enterprise-to-developerstandard/
- https://datarrett.com/72/how-to-easily-downgrade-sql-server-from-enterprise-to-developer-standard-edition
- [Downgrade SQL Server from Enterprise to Developer edition in an Availability Group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/280773/downgrade-sql-server-from-enterprise-to-developer-edition-in-an-availability-gro)
- https://www.littlekendra.com/2016/11/15/downgrading-the-sql-server-edition-of-a-dev-environment/